# Spine.js Unknown Record (possible scope error?)

Tags: javascript, spine.js

If I have a list of "albums," and I click on one, I navigate to another view (/#/album/:id) which is controlled by a controller called SingleAlbum. It fetches the data correctly, but I can't get it to render. I've looked over other 'Unknown Record' issues on SO and on the Spine Google Group, but no dice. Here's my code:

```
var SingleAlbum = Spine.Controller.sub({
    apiObj: {
        url: '/api/album',
        processData: true,
        data: {
            id: ''
        }
    },
    model: Album,
    panel: $('.album_single'),
    tmpl: $('#albumTpl'),

    init: function() {
        this.apiObj.url = this.model.url;
        if(this.panel.children.length > 0) {
            this.panel.html('');
        }
    },
    render: function(id) {
        console.log('render');

        var template = singleAlbum.tmpl.html(),
            data = Album.find(id), //  <--  this doesn't want to work
            html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
        singleAlbum.panel.html(html);
    },
    getData: function(id) {
        //var me = this;
        console.log('get data');
        this.apiObj.data.id = id;
        this.apiObj.url = this.model.url;

        this.model.bind('refresh change', function(id) {
            //me.render(id);
            singleAlbum.render(id);
            console.log('should be rendered');
        });

        this.model.fetch(this.apiObj);
        console.log('record: ',this.model.find(id));
        if(Object.keys(this.model.find(id)).length > 0) {
            //this.render(id);
        }
    }   

});
```

The problem happens when I call .render() on the event handler. I can manually see that Album.all() has records, and can do Album.find(id) anywhere else in the app, but when I do it on `var data = Album.find(id)` it fails. Is this a scope issue? Am I missing something obvious?

By the by, please excuse the verboseness of my code. I'm actually making a SingleItem controller, of which SingleArtist and SingleAlbum will be subclasses. I thought that might be an issue, so I ripped out the code to test it on it's own.

EDIT: Specifically, my route looks like this:

```
'/album/:id': function(params) {
    console.log('navigated to /album/', params.id);
    singleAlbum.getData(params.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! I was passing `id` in my event handler, which was overwriting the other id variable. Here's what it should look like:

```
render: function(id) {
        var template = this.tmpl.html(),
            data = this.model.find(id),
            html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
        this.panel.html(html);
},
getData: function(id) {
        var me = this;
        this.apiObj.data.id = id;
        this.apiObj.url = this.model.url;

        this.model.bind('refresh change', function() {  //  <--  don't need to pass anything
            me.render(id);
        });

        this.model.fetch(this.apiObj);
}
```